# Automatically wrap around methods with rescue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this [RailsCast on Facebook API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api). The following code allows to pass a block to `facebook` method and benefit from `rescue`.

```
  def facebook
     @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
     block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
   rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
     logger.info e.to_s
     nil # or consider a custom null object
   end

   def friends_count
     facebook { |fb| fb.get_connection("me", "friends").size }
   end
```

However, I have a dozen of methods that invoke `facebook` method defined here, and I don't want to repeat `facebook {}` within each of them. (The syntax is not particularly nice).

Is there a way to simplify this? Something like a filter that will wrap around each of methods invoking `facebook`.

Comment: your code is explicit, I'd keep it

Answer (score 1):

You can try delegation for this

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate more on how I can use delegate for this situation? I read the blog post but am still not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: curious to see delegation in this case too

Comment: The idea was that you could delegate to the @facebook instance in your function call but I guess you would have the problem then with not catching the exceptions there. I also upvoted "apneadiving"'s comment. I think you should just leave the code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's an older question, but I just ran across it and a possible answer, so I'll leave this here in case anyone else is interested.  It comes from [websocket-ruby](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-ruby).  The idea is to provide a consistent way to provide methods both with and without a rescue wrapper for your enjoyment.

```
module WebSocket
  module ExceptionHandler
    attr_accessor :error

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      # Rescue from WebSocket::Error errors.
      #
      # @param [String] method_name Name of method that should be wrapped and rescued
      # @param [Hash] options Options for rescue
      #
      # @options options [Any] :return Value that should be returned instead of raised error
      def rescue_method(method_name, options = {})
        define_method "#{method_name}_with_rescue" do |*args|
          begin
            send("#{method_name}_without_rescue", *args)
          rescue WebSocket::Error => e
            self.error = e.message.to_sym
            WebSocket.should_raise ? raise : options[:return]
          end
        end
        alias_method "#{method_name}_without_rescue", method_name
        alias_method method_name, "#{method_name}_with_rescue"
      end
    end
  end
end
```